# Get method for an API keeps getting 202 response

Tags: http, https, httpresponse

I have an http client written in c#(.net core) and I am trying to call a GET http API to download a file from it. But every first time I call this API it returns me a status code 202 and I have checked the documentation of the API it says 202 indicates the file is being transcoding. So right now I have some logic to get away with 202 response like this:

```
while(status == 202)
{
   Thread.sleep(60000);
}
if(status == 200)
{
   download the file....
}
```

I am just wondering if there are better ways to achieve this as sometimes it keeps getting 202 multiple times and the sleep time is long. If there is a better way please advise I would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'standard HTTP way' to do this, although it is possible for API's to do something. You will have to either consult the API documentation of the API you are using, or request this as a new feature.